# To pleasure someone, to bring pleasure to someone, to make someone happy

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference in meaning or nuance between "to pleasure someone" and "to bring pleasure to someone?"

What about between "to pleasure someone" and "to make someone happy?"

Answer (score 16):

"To pleasure somebody" is rather rare, and in modern English means *only* "to give sexual satisfaction to". Don't use it unless you mean that.

A less specific word is "gratify" - it can be used sexually, but it can also be used in a general sense.

"Bring pleasure to" and "make happy" are very close in meaning.

Answer (score 3):

*To pleasure someone* would usually involve sexual satisfaction. *To bring pleasure to someone* doesn't have that sense as strongly. This may be because the latter isn't used as commonly, so the listener takes the words at their immediate value.

*To make someone happy* would be similar to *to bring pleasure to someone* rather than *to pleasure someone*, for the reasons above.

*To please someone* would be a concise alternative that doesn't have sexual connotations.

Answer (score 0):

1. "To pleasure" means that there is an active party: a book may bring pleasure to you, or please you, but it cannot pleasure you. It often carries a sexual connotation, but not exclusively.
2. Happiness and pleasure are two distinct concepts: you may experience happiness without much pleasure in your life, and you can certainly live a life full of pleasure without being truly happy.

Comment: I have to at least partially disagree that *happiness and pleasure are two distinct concepts*. All of Merriam-Webster, TheFreeDictionary and Google define mention *pleased* or *pleasure* in their definitions for *happy*, and in their definitions for *pleasure* mention *enjoyment* or *delight*, which go through *joy* back to *happiness*. Even if there are subtle differences in some of their uses, they generally refer to the same thing. The main distinction, I'd say, is with *physical pleasure* as opposed to *pleasure* in general.

Answer (score -1):

"To pleasure someone" example: my boyfriend pleasures me.. not only by sexual activities but pleasures me by his sweet words, the caress of his hand to my hand & the genuine heart felt hug.

"To bring pleasure to someone" example:my boyfriends presence, the sound of his voice, the smile on his face, his unselfish caring ways to others ybrings me unspeakable pleasure. The look he gives me that reassures me of his love brings me PLEASURE!

"To make someone happy" example: doing for others in an unselfish manner. To make someone happy is  to put that person  before ones self & being satisfied just by the smile on their face.

As for couples..pleasure & happiness go hand in hand! The pleasure (both mentally & physically) that each other give one another brings true happiness! Giving 100% + Getting 100%= Love>happiness ♋️